# Maven Multiple module project in Eclipse issue

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I have multiple module maven project which i imported in eclipse.

mvn eclipse:eclipse

and it shows child modules as following.

[image]

problem is it is not recognizing any of the child modules java files. if hover objects it does not show up any thing and consider as plain text files. it complains that it is not in build path ???

any idea how to fix or how to import multip modules maven project in eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven support is included in Eclipse Kepler.  You can find it in the File -> Import screen as Maven -> Existing Maven Projects.

[image: Eclipse Maven Import]

Selecting a directory with a parent POM in it will prompt you to import all its children as well.

[image: Maven Import projects]

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down thatroad check out [this old school method](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/multi-module-projects.html) with `eclipse:eclipse` and multi-module import plugin.

But I have a different suggestion. Remove all `eclipse:eclipse` generated files, download [m2e](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) (new versions of Eclipse already include it). Then just use m2e [Import Maven Project](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html) feature. It will recognize nested `pom.xml` files and let you create separate projects out of the ones you choose to work with.

[image: Importing multiple projects]

**Source**: [m2eclipse-book](http://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html)