# How do I get my Eclipse JUnit test run to behave the same as running the test on the mvn command line?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, apache-httpclient-4.x, nosuchmethoderror

I’m using Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.9.1, Maven 3.1.1, JUnit 4.11, and have this Apache httpcomponents dependency:

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.4</version>
            </dependency>
```

When I run a JUnit test in Eclipse (by right clicking my test name, and selecting “Run As” -> “Junit Test”), I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse;
    at org.usersubscr.subco.ebook.mvc.CleverInstantLoginController.validateInstantAccessLogin(CleverInstantLoginController.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.mainco.subco.ebook.mvc.CleverInstantLoginControllerTest.submitLoginWithCode(CleverInstantLoginControllerTest.java:119)
    at org.mainco.subco.ebook.mvc.CleverInstantLoginControllerTest.testInstantLoginSuccess(CleverInstantLoginControllerTest.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The specific line where things are dying is

```
response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The frustrating thing about this is that when I run the same test on the command line, using

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=MyHttpTest
```

The test runs fine without the error.  I have tried running “mvn eclipse:eclipse” on my project and refreshing my workspace, but that doesn’t seem to help.  How can I get the Eclipse JUnit to behave the same way as running the test on the command line?

Comment: Please check this link, i delete it because it answered same at both pleace with this way avoid the duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437518/maven-multiple-module-project-in-eclipse-issue/24438113#24438113 Please specify is it solved your problem.

Comment: Also gave it a go but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently run into this problem.

If I am running from Maven, either from command line or from Eclipse, then I always do `mvn clean test`.

If I am running as JUnit from Eclipse, then I first do Project > Clean (followed by build), and finally Run as JUnit. If that still does not solve the problem, then I first do Maven Clean and repeat the procedure.

Bottom line is: Maven and Eclipse each have their own (strong) opinion on how the world works, and in certain cases they contradict each other.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but disappointingly got the same result.

Comment: @Dave Is everything in Eclipse uptodate? In Eclipse are there any build markers on your project? Just checking the obvious.

Comment: Yes, there are tons of build markers, but there things like "ArrayList is a raw type.  References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized."  I don't think this is what's causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, had this exact same problem with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils.isNotEmpty
```

For me this was because Hibernate includes commons-collections-3.1 which does not include method isNotEmpty(). I though it was really weird, as when I used m2e plugin Dependency Hierarchy feature, it showed me that it automatically excluded the dependency and used 3.2 instead. What's worse, it seemed that manually excluding the artifact from the pom did not do anything.

For me the problem was that I had Maven dependency with scope set to test and for some reason Eclipse JUnit used this dependency without exception. I have multi module project and I was trying to find out the problem in downstream module (that is, I was looking the dependency hierarchy of a module that included a module, which included another module, that had the dependency which caused problems), so Eclipse Maven plugin did not see the dependency as the scope was test. As said, JUnit did not understand that it should't use this dependency further down the road, and this gave me headache.

For you the problem might be something else, so I try to give more general picture to track the problem down. Following is the process I used to track and eliminate the issue, hope this helps:

1. used m2e plugin Dependency Hierarchy to track down all versions of the dependency
2. found out that Hibernate uses old dependency
3. went to my local m2 repo and renamed all incorrect versions (see image)

[image: renamed dependencies]

4. run tests (to verify we are on right track), they should fail saying that the dependency cannot be found
5. use Notepad++ to find all files that include the wrong dependency (for me the search string was "commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar" and file name filter was ".classpath")
6. find out the modules trying to use it
7. check the exact pom files and exclude the culprit (for me it was the following:)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```